# Should I Upload the Current Version of My Master's Thesis for PhD Application

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, thesis

I am currently a physics master's student and am applying to physics PhD programs this season. My master's defense will occur sometime after the application deadlines, and I will (hopefully) get additional feedback on my master's thesis during my defense presentation. My PhD applications do not specifically ask for a master's/undergraduate thesis and my advisor will be writing my letter. I also shared my master's results and the notes/derivations I made for my master's project to the other letter writers when I sent them recommendation requests. Is it necessary for me to upload my thesis for my applications when other people will write about my work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no section on the application form for it, I wouldn't upload it.

I doubt the people assessing the applications will have time to read an entire thesis, let alone hundreds (if every applicant uploaded one). Of course, you should discuss, or at least mention your past research experience in your research statement, but the time to talk about it in detail would be at the interview.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!